# Interpretaciòn de "I flatten out on my belly"

Tags: traducción

Estoy leyendo Los juegos del hambre en Inglés y en una parte del libro dice:

> I flatten out on my belly and slide under a two-foot stretch
>   that’s been loose for years.

Entiendo lo que quiere decir en general,lo que no entiendo es lo que significa:

> I flatten out on my belly

Si alguien me pudiera indicar lo que significa sería de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the meaning of an English sentence, not a Spanish one.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta aceptada, así que llego un poco tarde para este comentario, pero para la próxima vez, si al menos intentases una traducción al español para esa frase, o indicar qué problemas tienes para encontrar un equivalente en español sería más fácil mantener la pregunta _on-topic_ para este sitio. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flatten out my belly` significa apretarse la barriga..
En este caso, significa hacerse caber.   Hacerse ser capaz de pasar por el tramo... para que no se atasque.

EDIT**
En inglés , "flatten out my belly" sí significa lo que ya he escrito, pero hay un otro "sinónimo" que te hará poder entender mejor el dicho "flatten out my belly"..

```
Suck in your gut
```

Eso es la forma más comprensible y común.  Cómo el autor decidió usar la otra forma, `flatten out..`, es obvio que quería expresar una acción atlética; una acción que indica el uso de los músculos del estómago.

Busca Google por 'suck in your gut'

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=suck+in+your+gut+espa%C3%B1ol

Comment: Jaja , pues vaya, temí mal. Quito mi respuesta, pero antes podrías dar enlace a un diccionario o fuente? No lo vi en ningún sitio.

Comment: Se puede ver aquí http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flatten

Comment: Mi lengua materna es inglés.  Soy Americano.  Eso es mi fuente.

Answer (score 0):

En España decimos *meter tripa*, creo que se podría traducir así también.